# Explain the following output?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Please explain the output:

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
    int i= -3, j=2, k=0, m;
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
    cout<< i <<" " << j << " " << k <<" "<<m;
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT : 
-2 2 0 1**

Here's what I thought:
(++i || ++j) && (++k) //Considering the precedence order
++i becomes -2 so first part of OR true, so it won't check 2nd part.
*(Thanks  Joachim Pileborg for telling me the short circuit evaluation)*

So overall, first part of AND is true.
But that is not enough for statement to be true, 2nd part must be true to.
So ++k makes k = 1
Here's where I get it wrong. Why is k not increasing?

whereas, in this case:

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
    int i= -1, j=2, k=0, m;
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
    cout<< i <<" " << j << " " << k <<" "<<m;
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:
0 3 1 1**

I got this one too considering short circuit evaluation.

Comment: What did you not understand ? What did you expect ?

Comment: Remember that the logical operators uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: If in doubt, use brackets.  Relying on operator precidence is all well and good, but all it takes is one mistake.  In situations like this I prefer to define the 'order' of execution explicitly (precidence through`()`'s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with this code snippet

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
    int i= -3, j=2, k=0, m;
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
    cout<< i <<" " << j << " " << k <<" "<<m;
    return 0;
}
```

It is obvious that `m` will be have a boolean value converted to int. As `++i` is equal to -2 that is unequal to zero then all other expressions will not be evaluated because it is already known that the whole expression is equal to `true`. So after statement

```
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
```

`m` is equal to 1 and `i` is equal to -2 All other variables were not changed.

In this code snippet

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
    int i= -1, j=2, k=0, m;
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
    cout<< i <<" " << j << " " << k <<" "<<m;
    return 0;
}
```

`++i` will be equal to 0. So the right operand of `operator ||` will be evaluated. This operand is

```
++j && ++k
```

As `++j` will be equal to 3 and is not equal to 0 then `++k` also will be evaluated and will be equal to 1. As the both operands of `operator &&` is not equal to zero then the result is equal to `true`

Thus you will get i == 0, j == 3, k == 1, m == 1.

From the C++ Standard

**5.14 Logical AND operator**

> 1 The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). The result is true if both
>   operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, **&& guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the
>   first operand is false.**

**5.15 Logical OR operator**

> 1 The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It returns true if either
>   of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, **||
>   guarantees left-to-right evaluation; moreover, the second operand is
>   not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true.**

Comment: How had you put the brackets?
(++i || ++j) && (++k)
or
(++i) || (++j && ++k)

Comment: @lazygeek Expression  m = ++i || ++j && ++k; is equivalent to m = ( ++i || ( ++j && ++k ) );

Comment: Oh yes. Got it now.
Still wondering why I got -6 for this question though.

Comment: @lazygeek Now it is -5.:) I also wonder when questions of beginners when their meanings are clear are downvoted.

Comment: Its not the first time. Its my 3rd or 4th question. Sorry to say but some people are kinda rude, especially to the beginners.

Comment: I put -1 because your first question didn't explain your problem. You just said "Can you explain this output ?" without explain why it was strange for you...

Comment: WOW. The problem is now put on hold as it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In logical expressions, such as: `... || ... && ...` C++ can omit executing statements that would not change the output value of expression. For example: if it computes first value and it's output is not equal to 0, then expression: `true || ... && ...` is always true, therefore execution of further expressions is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Below is your second case:-

```
int i= -1, j=2, k=0, m;
m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
```

In

```
( cond1 || cond2)
```

expression if cond1 is true then compiler does not go on to check for cond2. It will evaluate cond2 only if cond1 returns false.

So, in second ++i makes first expression to be false and forces compiler to go on to evaluate further whereas in first case first expression returns true.